# Two dimentional array into single dimentional array without foreach PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Is there way to convert two dimentional array into single dimentional array without using foreach loop in php.

Below is the actual array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [male] => male
            [female] => female
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [male] => male1
            [female] => female1
        )
)
```

And **Output** will be like

```
Array
(
    [0] = > male
    [1] = > female
    [2] = > male1
    [3] = > female1
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce` and use `array_merge`

```
$array = array( ... ); //Your array here
$result = array_reduce($array, function($c,$v){
    return array_merge(array_values($c),array_values($v));
}, array());
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => male
    [1] => female
    [2] => male1
    [3] => female1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This loops through your multidimensional array and stores the results in the new array variable $newArray.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($multi as $array) {
 foreach($array as $k=>$v) {
  $newArray[$k] = $v;
 }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet might answer the question it is always better to add some explanation that might be useful to other readers too.